# Reason for large number of downvotes

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I am new to islam.stackexchange.com

I have experienced large number of down-votes without any explanations. I am also observing that many well written serious questions get many down-votes. As an [example](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/77150/differences-of-opinion-among-scholars) (**not my question**)

I am not saying the down-votes are wrong. However I would like to understand the reason for down-votes. Am I missing something about purpose of this site? What kind of questions are encouraged? Is something wrong with my responses or my presentation? Is it all in my imagination?

Please feel free to answer harshly, if you think it is required. However if I see down-vote without comment on this question, I will conclude it is a troll problem.

Edit: Large number of down-votes mean that I can't post any new answers now (although I am not banned) . I guess that is end of my engagement with this site. See you in heaven, Inshallah.

Comment: Right now, the linked question has exactly _one_ downvote. On your own account not even half your answers have any downvotes, and none have more than two. I wouldn't call that a "large number" by any stretch of the word.

Comment: It is at least two down-votes, once you consider the fact that I have up-voted it.

Comment: Down-votes are not a problem. Down-votes are essential for a healthy community. The problem is, all down-votes are without any explanation. Yesterday, I have received 3 down-votes and zero up-votes. It was same the day before yesterday.

Comment: @goldPseudo: As an example, look at this answer https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/77142/51720 It has 3 down-votes but zero comments.

Answer (score 3):

The default reason for any downvote is right there in the tooltip:

- **This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or
  not useful**
  [image]
- **This answer is not useful**
  [image]

I can't speak for why any individual post received downvotes. What the community finds "useful" is super subjective. Admittedly, people can vote — up or down — for whatever reason they want, but I've so far seen no reason to believe there's problematic voting going on here.

A lot of users aren't keen to leave a comment unless they feel their comments will be acted on; constructive criticism is often ignored and problematic posts remain unfixed whether comments are left or not. This is especially common with new users, who will often prefer to argue over criticism rather than accept it; the fact that you're willing to assume bad faith on the part of the community and chalk your downvotes up to a "troll problem" is particularly telling.

If you are honestly interested in contributing to the community, it behooves you to take the time to actually demonstrate your value. To demonstrate not only that you can actually heed community feedback when and if it's provided to you, but also *how* you respond to that feedback (and remembering that downvotes *are* feedback in and of themselves). To demonstrate that you can provide quality content, and to continue to provide and improve your content over time.

There are countless examples of highly upvoted posts that can be used as references. Meta is full of useful discussions on how to write a good answer. Being useful is a skill like any other, and like any other skill it can be learned, practiced, and perfected. You can even ask clear and focused questions *on* Meta to help you improve, but ultimately this is *your* content, and you really can't rely on others to help you provide it. There won't always be someone there to hold your hand.

Comment: Thanks for your response.